# blank page after dokuwiki upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, dokuwiki

I tried to upgrade [dokuwiki](http://wiki.sweconsulting.com) using its upgrade plugin wizard.  Upgrade went fine.  After upgrade when I brows the site, the landing page loads fine but as soon as I click anywhere in the browser, it brings up a black blank page.

I check the apache's error and access log and see nothing wrong there. Set the site's log level to debug. Checked the file permissions and they look ok.  Cleared the cache.

Anyone has any pointers on how and where to look further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by performing below steps:

Temporarily disable JavaScript in your browser, then use the extension manager to update all the extensions. Re-enable JavaScript afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue myself and this answer helped me. Once I disabled javascript I couldn't get to the admin page. I'd add to this answer, after you disable javascript you should be able to get to your admin page at an address similar to:

http://YOUR_DOMAIN_PATH/doku.php**?id=start&do=admin&page=extension**